# Powershell - add duplicate key but different values into a hash table

Tags: powershell, hashtable

how to add duplicate keys with different values into a hash table so it could be later used in a foreach loop in Powershell? i.e.

```
$VM = "computer1"

$HashTable = @{ }
$HashTable.Add("key", $VM)

...some script, if statements, ....

$VM = "computer2"
$HashTable.Add("key", $VM)
.....

ForEach ($machine in $HashTable.values)
{
do something for $machine
}
```

I get an error: 
"Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'key'  Key being added: 'key'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have duplicate keys in a Hash Table (or dictionary), but you can do this:

```
$HashTable = @{}

$VM = "computer1"
[Array]$HashTable['Key'] += $VM

$VM = "computer2"
[Array]$HashTable['Key'] += $VM

ForEach ($machine in $HashTable['Key'])
{
    Write-Host $Machine
}
```

But I really question if you want to do this. Instead, I guess your `$VM` is actually supposed to be the key and than you can do: `ForEach ($machine in $HashTable.Keys) {...}`

Comment: You are right. Anyway, I came up with using simple array:

$VM = "computer1"

$Array= @{ }
$Array +=$VM

...some script, if statements, ....

$VM = "computer2"
$Array +=$VM
.....

ForEach ($machine in $Array)
{
do something for $machine
}

Comment: Since this provided a pointer for you to resolve your problem, perhaps mark as answer?

Answer (score -1):

I have had to do a similar thing so I simply use an Array's of Dict/HT's. Works pretty great for my needs for duplicate keys done as duplicate Dict/HT's. Whatever methods/properties of your HT/Dict will be avail inside the array (list). Powershell is very good going over items inside lists.

Its easy to make List of HT's, Object of HT's, or HT's of Objects ad infinitum, and your means of access and retrieval should help you choose what you need.

Enjoy. HTH.

```
# using arraylist classic but works with any .
# then add HT's/Dict's of one item each .
$a = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
[Void]$a.Add( @{ "Dict_1" = "Val_1" } ) 
[Void]$a.Add( @{ "Dict_2" = "Val_2" } )
[Void]$a.Add( @{ "Dict_3" = "Val_3" } )
[Void]$a.Add( @{ "Dict_1" = "Val_1001" } )
# then you can use various methods to get items or go through them.
# as you are looking for you can get more than one item back (duplicates) from a search.
# this includes T/F 'containskey()' kind of searches.
# account for those methods and this works like a snap.
ForEach ($HT in $a)
{
   $HT['Dict_1']
}

$a.Keys
$a.Keys -eq 'Dict_1'
$a.GetEnumerator() | Where Keys -eq 'Dict_1'
$a.Values    
$a.ContainsKey('Dict_1') 
$a.ContainsValue('Val_1')
```

Comment: Are you affiliated with this site that has the near identical paragraph, https://codeutility.org/hashtable-powershell-add-duplicate-key-but-different-values-into-a-hash-table-stack-overflow/ no attribution / accreditation for the sources ?